# Is there any good tutorial (example) for unit testing kohana base project?

Tags: phpunit, kohana

I am looking for the best practices with PHPUnit testing a project on KohanaPHP framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kohana has a phpUnit module which is maintained by Ben Rogers, Chris Bandy, Isaiah DeRose-Wilson, Jeremy Bush, Kiall Mac Innes and Sam Clark.

You can find the module below and the documentation can be found [here](http://dev.kohanaphp.com/wiki/phpunit) and [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html).

http://dev.kohanaphp.com/projects/phpunit

Comment: The above link is now a 404.  This looks like the new place to go for it -- http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/phpunit

Comment: Actually, this article http://embrangler.com/2010/04/testing-in-kohana-3/ looks way better than the official docs / that project.  There is an open ticket on the official phpunit that has been open since '09